# how to display a coming soon page when a page doesn't have an index page using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, errordocument

my directory looks like this:

```
/
/comingsoon.php
/.htaccess
/domain1.com/ < folder
/domain2.com/ < folder
```

i can access domain1.com on maindomain.com/domain1.com or simply domain1.com

i want to display comingsoon.php when i get an 403 error. i tried this:

ErrorDocument 403 /comingsoon.php

but it only works on maindomain.com/domain1.com/ but not in domain1.com

and i don't want to put comingsoon.php inside domain1.com, i just want it in the root, coz i have a lot of accounts

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that for `http://domain1.com/`, you've got the document root pointed to `/domain1.com/`, which means it will never be able to access files outside of the document root. You'll need to move the comingsoon.php file to the `/domain1.com/` folder and include the same `ErrorDocument`.

Another option is to include the full hostname in the original error document:

```
ErrorDocument 403 http://maindomain.com/comingsoon.php
```

But this will change the location in the browser's address bar.